# UIImageView overlapping effect inside a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uitouch, touchesmoved

Check this URL http://krystalrae.com/
Scrolling down you will see a girl's cloths are changing on mouse wheel scrolling.

[image]

I have to create a `iPad application` where 3 images will appear likewise. The difference will be that in my case image change will occur `horizontally` rather than `vertically` in website. Also, i have to make it inside UIView with events `touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded and touchesCancelled`

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: 2 UIImageviews img1, img2 side by side. img1 frame is full frame and img2 frame width is 0f. 
Swiping rights to left decreasing img1 width and increasing img2 width and decreasing x axis. But this distorts the imageviews. Is there any possibility to decrease UIImageView width will cut the image inside imageview rather than scaling, fitting that? Something like in a HTML table if you have a background image set then increasing-decreasing table width does not resizes back image but it shows rest of the image.
Anything new will be welcome but that should be done using UIView delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I gather that the problem is the resizing of the images in `UIImageView` when changing the bounds of the view.

You can set the `contentMode` of the image view to something else. The default is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` which is not what you want.

You could, for example, set the lower image view to `UIViewContentModeBottom`, and the upper image view to `UIViewContentModeTop`.

Don't forget to make sure your image views have sett the property `maskToBounds` set as `YES`.

Comment: i just found UIViewContentModeTopLeft is working what i wanted. Let me rectify this whole issue now, will you know again. Thanks sir :)

Comment: no, this is also not working. Suppose image dimension is 100x100 but UIImageView frame is 50x100 then how to display partial image inside that frame!

Comment: You have to set the property `masksToBounds` to `YES`.

Comment: you mean `UIImageViewObject.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`, yes you are right. Please mention that also in your Answer above.